# golang 2 go routines if one terminates terminate the other one

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

so I am using gorillas websocket library and I'm building a websocket server when I receive a connection I create 2 go routines one to read incoming messages from the client and another 1 to listen for in coming messages sent to the channel and then send them to the client.

```
func (p *Player) EventLoop() {
    l4g.Info("Starting player %s event loop", p)
    go p.readFromSocket()
    go p.writeToSocket()

    //blocks until we receive an interrupt from the read channel
    <-p.closeEventChan
    p.cleanup() //nothing else to do so lets cleanup
}

func (p *Player) writeToSocket() {
    for m := range p.writeChan {
        if p.conn == nil {
            break
        }

        if reflect.DeepEqual(network.Packet{}, m) == true {
            break
        }

        if err := p.conn.WriteJSON(m); err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    p.closeEventChan <- true
}

func (p *Player) readFromSocket() {
    for {
        if p.conn == nil {
            break
        }

        m := network.Packet{}

        if err := p.conn.ReadJSON(m); err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    p.closeEventChan <- true
}

func (p *Player) Cleanup() {

    //make sure the channels get a close message which will break us out of the go routines
    close(p.writeChan)
    close(p.closeEventChan)

    //only close the connection if we have a connection
    if p.conn != nil {
        p.conn.Close()
        p.conn = nil
    }
}
```

my problem is if we leave the `readFromSocket()` loop `Cleanup()` is called however we never leave the `writeToSocket()` loop ! this problem can be simpler demonstrated in this go playground  https://play.golang.org/p/49bh7bbbG-

how can we fix this so if we leave the `writeToSocket()` loop we also leave the `readFromSocket()` loop and vice vesa?

I was under the impression that this would work as if you call close on a channel (`close(p.writeChan)`) the default value that the channel accepts will be sent

Comment: The program just exits before the message is written.

Comment: could this cause a memory leak? as we exit the function before the go routine terminates? (obviously this isn't a problem in the playground example as the entire program terminates) or will go take care of that for me?

Comment: In the play example no, but in you main example there is a problem because you are sending a value to `closeEventChan` two times and if that `chan` is not buffered one of them will block forever on sending.

Comment: Another problem you have is checking/setting `conn` to `nil` without any synchronization.

Comment: I made a mistake, the send will not block forever, you are closing that channel. The send on a closed channel will panic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually do this with a shared quit channel, and some counting.

```
func (p *Player) writeToSocket(quit <-chan struct{})
    defer func() {
        p.closeEventChan <- true
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            return
        case m := <-p.writeChan:
            // Do stuff
        // Case where writeChan is closed, but quit isn't
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}


func (p *Player) readFromSocket(quit <-chan struct{})
    defer func() {
        p.closeEventChan <- true
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            return
        default:
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}

func (p *Player) EventLoop() {
    l4g.Info("Starting player %s event loop", p)
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    go p.readFromSocket(quit)
    go p.writeToSocket(quit)

    //blocks until we receive an interrupt from the read channel
    <-p.closeEventChan
    close(quit)
    // This is superfluous here, but in a different case
    // you loop over the remaining number of workers using a NumWorkers variable
    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        <-p.closeEventChan
    }
    p.cleanup() //nothing else to do so lets cleanup
}
```

The idea here is that:

1. All workers notify the central routine upon close via a channel before returning.
2. All workers return upon a quit message being broadcast (via close).
3. The central loop closes the quit channel after the first worker exits, then waits for the rest to exit.